# how to add text to event in fullcalendar-v4

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

i am trying to make schedule where user can see when he was absent or work or something else in monthly calendar. I am using fullcalendar  and i came across to problem with adding text on events day. there are what i've done and what i want to

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3dIj.png)

and this is what i want  to trying to do
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAzIa.jpg)

how can i do that? please help me

this is my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtsqt.png)

Comment: Please do not add images of your code. Code is **text**, so please paste it into your question as text, and use the [formatting tools available](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to make sure it's presented correctly. Pictures of code are useless to us when trying to help you - we can't search through them, or copy them to write answers, or use the code to make a working demo. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. It looks like you are setting your events as "background" events. This causes the calendar not to show their titles etc. If you want the text to show, then don't set them as background events. You can then show text, and you can still set colours etc to show the different statuses.

Comment: i would suggest return your events array in json format and bind your calendar in client side. it would be better to understand what is returning from your server.